# Why is my React component that keeps track of state history not visually rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I have a large more complex component that is not behaving the way I expect, and I narrowed it down to a simpler component here:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App(props) {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([props.arr]);
  const [currentHistoryIndex, setCurrentHistoryIndex] = useState(0);
  const itemsRef = useRef(null);

  function handleButtonClick() {
    //Step 1: Manipulate the DOM directly.
    //I want the user to do this but here I'm hardcoding functionality for convenience.
    itemsRef.current.insertBefore(
      itemsRef.current.children[2],
      itemsRef.current.children[1]
    );

    //Step 2: Read the DOM
    const newArr = [...itemsRef.current.children].map(e => e.innerText);

    //Rerender with new values
    setHistory([...history, newArr]);
    setCurrentHistoryIndex(currentHistoryIndex + 1);
  }

  //Click the button, and it shows that it should render the updated array. Yet visually, the DOM does not update.
  console.log(history, currentHistoryIndex);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="items" ref={itemsRef}>
        {history[currentHistoryIndex].map((item, i) => (
          <div key={i}>{item}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App arr={["Cow", "Dog", "Fox", "Turtle", "Zebra"]} />,
  rootElement
);
```

Here is a codepen link: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sea-4hitw

The purpose of the component is to display an array of values (see `arr` prop passed). However, I want to be able to change this array and keep track of a history of these arrays, in order to support undo/redo down the road.

When you click the button, I want some sort of DOM manipulation to occur. Then I want to read the DOM with vanilla JS, then I want to update the history state based on this reading. Now I expect the component to rerender visually, but it does not. However if I click the button again it renders.

The amazing thing is that console.logging in the `render` method shows that the data is available; it's just not rendering.

I know that normally you don't do direct DOM manipulation in react but I have my reasons and I don't see why this would behave in this way. Is there an explanation for this odd behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why [you shouldn't use index as a key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). React uses the key to determine if the element has changed and whether it should be re-rendered. That's why keys should be unique to the content.

When you loop through the array, you're assigning the index of the array as the key, which stays always the same even though the content changes. React thinks that nothing has changed because the keys are identical and in the same order as during the previous render.

If you make the keys unique to what you're printing it starts working.

```
{history[currentHistoryIndex].map((item) => (
  <div key={item}>{item}</div>
))}
```